# iPhone Device to Device communication over Wifi

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have requirement like, One iPhone Device acts as a server and several iPhone devices acts as a clients.I have to communicate the client devices to the Server Device over Wifi.
How Can I achieve this. It would be appreciated if Could you provide any tutorial.
Thanks in Advance..

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/8116004/352891

Answer (score 0):

***!!! NOTE:

Below answer suggests an API that has been deprecated since iOS 7.***

---

you are looking at [GKSession](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKSession_Class/Reference/Reference.html).. and [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/14618/how-to-make-a-simple-playing-card-game-with-multiplayer-and-bluetooth-intro-and-challenge) is an excellent and comprehensive tutorial for what you're looking for. IF you wanna dive a little deeper take a look at this [project](https://github.com/abbood/iphoneAudioSyncer) I made.

the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8116004/352891) in the comment above uses [bonjour](https://developer.apple.com/bonjour/), which is a layer below GKSession (ie GKSession is a wrapper for bonjour).. so depending on how many devices you want to connect at a time (GKSession starts choking around 3-4) and how extensive your throughput/ping requirements are, you'd chose one or the other.

Answer (score 0):

Please look at following links these may be useful to you

[Cocoa Http server.](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaHTTPServer)

[how-to-make-ios-application-act-as-web-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12209302/how-to-make-ios-application-act-as-web-server)

[communicate-between-iphone-devices-over-the-3g-networ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11241026/for-my-task-how-should-you-communicate-between-iphone-devices-over-the-3g-networ)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Game Kit class. Game Kit provides classes that implement the low-level networking infrastructure to allow the devices to exchange data in real time.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is reading this in/after 2018, the current approach is:

`MultipeerConnectivity`

Docs:

*MultipeerConnectivity*
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/multipeerconnectivity

*Cross Platform Nearby Networking*
https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2014/709/

(`GKSession` has been deprecated since iOS 7)